# How to match exact pattern using FlexSearch

Tags: javascript, search

Is there a way to have FlexSearch (https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch) find only results that contains exact character sequence ? I tried to put resolution to 25 and threshold at 22 as suggested, play around with Depth also, but I keep getting words that are close (sometimes a bit far, but at least the length is matching) but not always exactly matching my sequence.

my indexed words are sometime 3 letters acronyms, so maybe it messes up the contextual search.

If you play with the following code snippet, by entering CTD you get CTD (ok) and CDT (not ok.) If you enter CAA, you get CAA (ok) and Candidate (not ok)

```js
        var data =["CTD","CDT", "Candidate","CRT","CAA"];
            (function(){

                const index = new FlexSearch.Index({
                    charset: "latin:advanced",
                    tokenize: "full",
                    resolution : 25,
                    threshold : 22,
                    cache: true
                });

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    index.add(i, data[i]);
                }

                var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
                var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");

                userinput.addEventListener("input", show_results, true);

                function show_results(){

                    var value = this.value;
                    var results = index.search(value);
                    var entry, childs = suggestions.childNodes;
                    var i = 0, len = results.length;

                    for(; i < len; i++){

                        entry = childs[i];

                        if(!entry){
                            entry = document.createElement("div");
                            suggestions.appendChild(entry);
                        }

                        entry.textContent = data[results[i]];
                    }

                    while(childs.length > len){
                        suggestions.removeChild(childs[i])
                    }
                }
            }());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FlexSearch Sample</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FlexSearch/0.7.31/flexsearch.compact.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="Search by keyword...">
        <br></br>
        <div id="suggestions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am probably missing something there but I believe there is a way to have the library generate a **dumber** index and exact matches rather than such a smart one with close matches.

Comment: Is the FlexSearch you're referencing [`nextapps-de/flexsearch`](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch)? If not, can you include a link to the specific library you're referencing here?

Comment: Can you share how you've configured you FlexSearch instance/index in your code as a [mre]?

Comment: I added a code snippet so that my problem is illustrated

Answer (score 1):

Does this *match* your requirements?

P.S.

To avoid wasting time searching for diffs: I changed only the `FlexSearch.Index` call options.

```js
var data = ["CTD", "CDT", "Candidate", "CRT", "CAA"];
(function() {

  const index = new FlexSearch.Index({
    charset: "latin",
    tokenize: "full",
    matcher: "simple",
    cache: true
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    index.add(i, data[i]);
  }

  var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
  var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");

  userinput.addEventListener("input", show_results, true);

  function show_results() {

    var value = this.value;
    var results = index.search(value);
    var entry, childs = suggestions.childNodes;
    var i = 0,
      len = results.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {

      entry = childs[i];

      if (!entry) {
        entry = document.createElement("div");
        suggestions.appendChild(entry);
      }

      entry.textContent = data[results[i]];
    }

    while (childs.length > len) {
      suggestions.removeChild(childs[i])
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>FlexSearch Sample</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nextapps-de/flexsearch@master/dist/flexsearch.compact.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="Search by keyword...">
  <br></br>
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm pleased, @Zzirconium

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more thoughts to Daniele Ricci's answer : sometimes the "simple" matcher still picks up false positives (if we are looking for strict pattern) if request contains numbers. Again, my approach is probably too empirical to get a completely correct behavior, but here is an example that produces false positives. Changing tokenize to strict improves the situation but then you lose the matching for partial words. default matcher seems to be the one with less false positive... still some remain... :(

If you input C3, or C0 or 4, you get them...

```js
var data = ["CA", "VIS-CD", "CATDIR-U"];

(function() {

  const index = new FlexSearch.Index({
    tokenize: "full",
    matcher: "default",
    cache: true
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    index.add(i, data[i]);
  }

  var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
  var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");

  userinput.addEventListener("input", show_results, true);

  function show_results() {

    var value = this.value;
    var results = index.search(value);
    var entry, childs = suggestions.childNodes;
    var i = 0,
      len = results.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {

      entry = childs[i];

      if (!entry) {
        entry = document.createElement("div");
        suggestions.appendChild(entry);
      }

      entry.textContent = data[results[i]];
    }

    while (childs.length > len) {
      suggestions.removeChild(childs[i])
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>FlexSearch Sample</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FlexSearch/0.7.31/flexsearch.compact.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="Search by keyword...">
  <br></br>
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
</body>

</html>
```