# How to match exact numerical pattern using FlexSearch

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to have FlexSearch (https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch) find only results that contains exact character sequence including numerical characters ?

The documentation is there : https://flexsearch.net/docs/flexsearch-manual.pdf
There is a section page 35 called Analyzer that seems to give hints on how to do, but there is a TODO note at the end when is expected the list of Analyzer that we could try alternatively.

The following thread works fine only for plain characters : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69677055/2143734

Or if you know any equivalent efficient and browser compatible search API, it is just that I seem to miss something there !

If you input C3, 1, C0 or 4, you get results although none of these numbers appears...

```js
var data = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys()).map(String);
data.unshift("CA", "VIS-CD", "CATDIR-U", "UE5", "GAE");

(function() {

  const index = new FlexSearch.Index({
    tokenize: "full",
    matcher: "default",
    cache: true
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    index.add(i, data[i]);
  }

  var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
  var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");

  userinput.addEventListener("input", show_results, true);

  function show_results() {

    var value = this.value;
    var results = index.search(value);
    var entry, childs = suggestions.childNodes;
    var i = 0,
      len = results.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {

      entry = childs[i];

      if (!entry) {
        entry = document.createElement("div");
        suggestions.appendChild(entry);
      }

      entry.textContent = data[results[i]];
    }

    while (childs.length > len) {
      suggestions.removeChild(childs[i])
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>FlexSearch Sample</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nextapps-de/flexsearch@master/dist/flexsearch.compact.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="Search by keyword...">
  <br></br>
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`find only results that contains exact character sequence`

ok, so instead of `Array.prototype.includes` logic, I used a cache system for the kind of search you want :D

```js
var data = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys()).map(String);
data.unshift("CA", "VIS-CD", "CATDIR-U", "UE5", "GAE");
//in essence, you can just change the condition(match_condition) to append a result based on whatever other condition you want
//the edit has me changing the match condition :D
//the edit also has me attempting a cache block(for speed)
(function() {
  var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
  var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");
  
  var cacheText={}, resultLimit=100, length=Symbol(null) //I'm doing caching based on how you want results(as in your snippet this part will lag a bit)
  for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(typeof data[i]!="string"){continue}
    for(let j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
      let string="" //for caching all direct text indexes
      for(let k=0;k<=j;k++){string+=data[i][k]}
      if(!cacheText[string]){
        cacheText[string]={[data[i]]:true}
        cacheText[string][length]=1 //length measurement
      }
      else{
        if(cacheText[string][length]==resultLimit){continue}
        cacheText[string][data[i]]=true
        cacheText[string][length]++ //adding to length
      }
    }
  }
  
  userinput.addEventListener("input", show_results, true);

  function show_results() {
    var {value}=this, values={}
    let match_condition=(text)=> cacheText[value]?cacheText[value][text]:false && value!="" //match condition(that you can change to whatever other logic)
    for(let i=0; i<suggestions.children.length; i++){
      //the purpose of this loop is to only remove elements that won't be on the new result list
      let matchCondition=()=>
      !suggestions.children[i]? true: //test(if child still exists)
      match_condition(suggestions.children[i].innerText) //condition(in this case if data exactly includes user input)
      
      while(!matchCondition()){ suggestions.children[i].remove() } //remove only those which won't match up to the condition
      if(!suggestions.children[i]){break} //end loop(since if this is true, there is no child left)
      values[suggestions.children[i].innerText]=true //to indicate that this value already exists when doing the second loop below
    }
    for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      //the purpose of this loop is to append UNIQUE results
      if(match_condition(data[i]) && !values[data[i]]){
        var child=document.createElement('div')
        child.innerText=data[i]
        suggestions.appendChild(child)
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="Search by keyword..." />
  <br></br>
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does perform the job, though I should have specified that I have a much bigger dataset to search into, hence my use of an index based search solution such as flexsearch... now maybe includes() is optimized in such a way but I would expect it to be implemented on a sequential search isn't it ?

Comment: caching is set to true because before the result of a user input is cached, the input would be tested along the entire array ;-; also if my answer's right can you please mark?

Comment: I cannot validate your answer because search performance is key, hence the use of a dedicated searching library. I changed the data array init in my snippet, if you use the same array, you will see that each search takes several seconds in your case, when flexsearch gives you an instant answer

Comment: fair point.. so I'm trying caching now >:D

Comment: one edit.. for each search result I properly implement limiting to the amount of values with `resultLimit` being `100`

Comment: I reckon you are tough and skillfull at implementing a standalone solution for my problem, and I want to to emphasize that. As my primary concern is to ultimately understand if flexsearch can or not perform what I want, I will now start a bounty for this question. If there is no answer to my questions when it expires, I will mark your answer as accepted, and grant you the bounty :)

Comment: oh, I see.. fair enough :D

Comment: You get the bounty. I keep the question unanswered in case I end up with some canonical solution, or a definitive no from the library creators (as they seem to be the only one knowing (or caring)